# How to replace "/" with "\ /" in unix-solaris

Tags: unix, awk, sed, solaris

For example : `3/12/1991` should get converted to `3\/12\/1991`.

That is, I want to replace `/` with `\/` [slash with backslash and slash].

Comment: In a variable? Text in a file? A file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed 's|/|\\/|g'`, maybe?

```
echo 3/12/1991 | sed 's|/|\\/|g'
3\/12\/1991
```